# What non-alphanumeric in <input> element should be avoided

Tags: html, validation, input

In the HTML input such as "type:password" and "type:Password", I was thinking of allowing the non-alphanumeric characters but second thought I think it might problem some security concern on it and also when I processing the value, which I might run into difficult. Should I exclude out totally or just allow certain characters? what do you guys thinks?

[This is the list of all the non-alphanumeric character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVY6W.png)

Comment: non-alphanumeric characters have become increasingly important for having a secure password, I would not exclude them. Any filtering should be done on the back-end.

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, asking for opinions is off-topic; see the [help/dont-ask]. Generally, it's self-defeating to disallow special characters, and there really shouldn't be much more processing that needs to be done, assuming a sane backend system.